# maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 in java

Tags: java, hibernate

I have to pass more than 1000 records in sqlquery in DAO (Hibernate). But the code below gives me the error: "maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 in java"

```
try{
        session =HibernateFactoryUtil.getTessSessionFactory().openSession();    
        String genQuery = new TmsAssetDataQueryUtil().genFilterBasedAssetDataQuery(filterBean);         
        SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(genQuery); 
        if(postFilter.getModels()!= null)   { sqlQuery.setParameterList("modelList",postFilter.getModels()); }         }
```

Comment: Also, I tried using disjuction, but as it is not collection I can't pass it to sqlQuery.setParameterList()

Comment: Did you try splitting the list into smaller pieces?

Answer (score 0):

This is an oracle limitation, you can't pass list longer than 1000 elements. The easiest hack is to divide the list in `n` sublists each smaller than size 1000 and perform your query for each sublist, and merge the results.

Comment: private Disjunction addCriteriaIn (String modelList, LinkedList Models)
 {
  ArrayList test=null;
   Disjunction dis = Restrictions.disjunction();
   if(Models.size()>1000)
   {        
     while(Models.size()>1000)
     {
      java.util.List<Long> subList = Models.subList(0, 1000);
       dis.add(Restrictions.in("modelList", subList));
       Models.subList(0, 1000).clear();
     }
   }
   dis.add(Restrictions.in("modelList", Models));
   //test.add(dis);
   return dis;
   //.add(dis);
 }

Comment: I tried using disjunction, but it won't work with sqlQuery.setParameterList

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: if(postFilter.getModels() != null) 
    {   
Models=postFilter.getModels();
    Disjunction test=addCriteriaIn("modelList",Models);  sqlQuery.setParameterList("modelList", test); }

Comment: sqlQuery.setParameterList won't allow me to pass disjunction, it gives error  : The method setParameterList(String, Collection) in the type Query is not applicable for the arguments (String, Disjunction)